# (NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED) through firefox same code works for safari

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I am getting **(NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED)** error  when I try to access the Javascript code through firefox.I get this error in the contents tab of HTTPFOX.

I googled and set the parameters of browser in config file as specified in this site but it still doesn't work.

http://code.google.com/p/httpfox/issues/detail?id=20

Can somebody suggest whats going wrong since the same code works fine for safari browser..

Comment: you don't use httpfox in safari, so it's comparing apples to oranges. Is the problem with Firefox or with httpfox?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? Fiddler is showing a 200 response, but it has a big red circle with a cross next to it.

Comment: @MikeKusold I think I may have found a fix. See my answer =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested in a solution to this, I believe it's to do with the plugin noscript. Disabling it fixed this, but I have yet to work out what part of noscript was causing the issue. Will update if I find out.

Edit:My issues was with a twitter auth callback. In the Advanced settings of noscript under ABE, in the SYSTEM ruleset, on the line "Accept from LOCAL" I added "*.twitter.com". This allowed callback requests from *twitter.com to return to a local address.

Answer (score 0):

On my macbook I had to uninstall firefox completely to correctly get the content of an ajax response with httpfox. This also implies to remove the firefox profile bij removing this Firefox folder (I could only find it via the terminal and not via Finder):

```
/Users/<YOURUSER>/Library/Application Support/Firefox
```

Then install firefox again and install the httpfox add-on.
I tried many cache settings also by entering about:config in the firefox URL however without succes. Be aware that removing the profile settings like I describe will also remove all your personal firefox customization. It concerned firefox 18.0.2 and httpfox 0.8.11.

Answer (score 0):

We used to get the same error when our JavaScript made an XMLHTTPRequest to the server. On the server side, we had java, and the java response, the content type was not explicitly set to "text/html". When that was done

```
resp.setContentType("text/html");
```

the error went away.